# Why few packages of python doesn't support in Azure Function V2?

Tags: python-3.x, azure, docker, azure-functions, azure-functions-core-tools

I'm trying to publish my app to azure function from visual studio code, 
and the following are my dependencies,

```
    pyodbc==4.0.26
pandas==0.25.0
numpy==1.16.4
azure-eventhub==1.3.1
```

and when I'm publishing my app I get the following error, 
**ERROR: cannot install cryptography-2.7 dependency: binary dependencies without wheels are not supported.  Use the --build-native-deps option to automatically build and configure the dependencies using a Docker container. More information at https://aka.ms/func-python-publish**

Answer (score 0):

This is a limitation of the way azure functions uses pip to download wheels. cryptography uploads an `abi3` manylinux wheel, but this command can't successfully download it. For more information (and a workaround) see: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-core-tools/issues/1150

Answer (score -1):

The link in the error message does answer your exact question:

> If you're using a package that requires a compiler and does not support the installation of many linux-compatible wheels from PyPI, publishing to Azure will fail

If you ask for the "why was it designed in this way?" - that's a different question and out of scope for StackOverflow. You might want to try on the [Functions Github](https://github.com/Azure/Azure-Functions#issues--feature-requests)

Comment: Interestingly, cryptography does publish manylinux wheels (as seen here: https://pypi.org/project/cryptography/#files ). Is there some specific constraint (e.g. must support 32-bit manylinux1 or "can't use abi3 for py3 wheels") that is here or is the questioner encountering a bug?